# А подскажите алгоритм по визуальному отображению таблиц и БД

Tags: sql, алгоритм

Сама задумка такая, пройтись по списку всех таблиц, нарисовать эти таблицы в виде квадратиков и меду таблицами (квадратиками) нарисовать связи в случае внешних ключей, причем так что бы эти самые связи не пересекались визуально с другими таблицами (квадратиками).

Comment: Может таки не алгоритм а программу? Алгоритм дорого будет стоить, да и комбинаций много 1-язык (с++/с#/java...) 2-формат изображения (doc/wmf/pdf/svg) 3-провайдер доступа к базе через (ole/odbc/jdbc/navive/....)

Comment: @nick_n_a   именно алгоритм, я думаю должен быть где то на просторах интернета описан алгоритм такой штуки, просто не совсем понятно как запрос сформулировать :)

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример одного из простейших способов для данной задачи.

1. Получаем список таблиц.
2. Отрисовываем их (квадраты) вдоль окружности.
3. Отрисовываем связи между ними.

При таком подходе, связи между таблицами не будут пересекать другие таблицы (квадраты).

Другие же способы можно также поискать в Интернете по ключевым запросам "[Визуализация графов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B2)" и "Алгоритм отрисовки графов".

Comment: Спасибо, с кругом фигня может выйти если надо построить связь межу узлами расположенными через один. Но это если я хочу связь прямую. А я вот не подумал что можно и криво связь нарисовать. Буду думать. Спасибо еще раз